# ¿Por que no se envía el correo usando el SMTP de Office365?

Tags: email, smtp

El problema es el siguiente: tengo un desarrollo de un sistema que registra las inscripciones de personas a ciertos llamados a inscripción. Cuando una persona confirma su inscripción, se ejecuta un bloque de código que envía un email de confirmación a la persona registrada.

Tengo configurados los siguientes parámetros:

- Host SMTP: smtp.office365.com
- Puerto SMTP: 587
- La opción de comunicación segura está desactivada.
- Indico que requiere autenticacion contra el SMTP cuando se envía el correo.
- Usuario: correo con el que quiero que salga.
- Password: contraseña de la cuenta de correo.

Si yo configuro mi cuenta personal de trabajo dentro de los parámetros de Usuario y Contraseña funciona todo correctamente, el correo llega al destinatario. Ahora cuando configuro otra cuenta que tenemos disponible y que es la que quiero utilizar para que envíe los correos, el proceso falla mostrando el siguiente error:

```
"Error sending message - 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [CP2P215CA0040.LAMP215.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM".
```

En los parametros tengo especificado que se autentique al momento de enviar el correo, pero pareciera que no logra hacerlo.

Desde mi servidor, tengo llegada al puerto 587 del SMTP de Office365.

¿Por qué con una cuenta personal de trabajo funciona y con otra cuenta no? Que detalle estoy omitiendo?

Comment: No te va a dejar autenticar por el 587 sin usar TLS. Si revisas los parámetros requeridos para usar el SMTP, vas a ver que así lo indica. SSL off, TLS on

Answer (score 0):

Estimado @Cristian2500

Desde *Power Shell* conectado al tenant debes ejecutar el siguiente comando para activar la autenticación *smtp* sobre el buzón a usar para los envíos (reemplaza UsuarioX por el buzón a usar):

```
Set-CASMailbox -Identity UsuarioX -SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled $false
```

Los comandos para conectar al tenant:

```
Install-Module MSOnline

Import-Module MSOnline

$UserCredential = Get-Credential

Connect-MSOLService -credential:$UserCredential 

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
```

Espero sea de ayuda!!! Saludos